# primeFaces : fileUpload to byte[]

Tags: forms, jsf, file-upload, primefaces, arrays

I am trying to get the uploaded image of `<p:fileUpload>` as `byte[]` and persist it in DB by JPA. But I'm facing a problem and I'm not even sure if I'm coding it the right way.

This is the entity:

```
@Entity
class Object { 
  @Lob
  @Column(name = "image")
  private byte[] image;
  //... 
}
```

Managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
class MyBean {

   private Object ob = new Object();

   @EJB 
   private ObjectFacadeLocal of;

   public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
      byte[] content = event.getFile().getContents();
      ob.setImage(content);
   }

   public String submit() {
      //...
      of.create(ob);
      return "anotherpage"
   }
```

The `ObjectFacade` persists `Object` in database.

This is the JSF page called `form.xhtml`:

```
<h:form id = "upi" enctype = "multipart/form-data"> 
    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{MyBean.handleFileUpload}"   
          allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;" description="Images"/>  
    <h:commandButton value = "Submit" action = "#{MyBean.create()}">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

First of all, I'm getting a warning in `form.xhtml` that it cannot find the `handleFileUpload` method, but I can still run it. When I press the submit button, then nothing happens, the page just refreshes. If I remove the `enctype` attribute then the object gets persisted, but not with the image.

Any ideas?

---

**Update**:

This is my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee /web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/blog.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to read the [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html). Here's an extract of `<p:fileUpload>` chapter:

> #### Getting started with FileUpload
>
> First thing to do is to configure the fileupload filter which parses the multipart request. FileUpload filter should map to Faces Servlet.
>
> ```xml
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
> <filter-mapping>
>     <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
>     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```

Without that filter, no one action method inside a `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">` can be invoked nor will the submitted data be properly parsed.

As to the warning that the method cannot be found, this is related to the IDE which you're using which is pretending to be smarter than it is. Disable EL validation in that IDE to avoid those confusing warnings and look if you can't upgrade the IDE.

Comment: sory for my ignorance but I add those same tags without changing anything to web.xml file right, cause I did that and nothing happend, it persists the object with no image, it doesn't go inside the handleFileUpload method. BTW Im using Netbeans version 7.0.1

Comment: Make sure that it is mapped to the faces servlet (i.e. the `<servlet-name>` must be exactly the servlet name of the faces servlet as you have in your `web.xml`). Also make sure that you still have the right `enctype` set.

Comment: Yes I've forgotten tu put enctype="multipart/form-data" im my form, and now after I did I get the same old thing, after I press Submit the page just refreshes, and the sevlet name is the same

Comment: Do you have other filters in your `web.xml`? If so, which?

Comment: After revising your question once again, I actually see some noise and inconsitencies, but this may be because you oversimplified the question and did not do that carefully. What scope does your managed bean really have? It should be `@ViewScoped` to get this construct to work. Also your managed bean name is not specified, so you can only access it by `#{myBean}`, not by `#{MyBean}`. Also the classes should be `public` and the class name `Object` is strongly discouraged as you're hiding the `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: thanks for taking time and helpiong me I appreciate it.Yes I didnt pay atention while writing,just for simplicity I used Object class and its myBean in my code however the bean is sessionscoped and I cant change that to viewscope