# When I use o:graphicImage, the image is not displayed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, omnifaces, graphicimage

I can´t display images from my database, they are stored as **bytea** and I am mapping them like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "photograph", schema = "public")
public class Photograph{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "photograph_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "diagnostic_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Diagnostic diagnostic;

    @Column(name = "photo", nullable = false)
    private byte[] photo;

    @Column(name = "photograph_description", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String photographDescription;

    @Column(name = "photograph_content_type")
    private String photographContentType;

//Getters and Setters...
}
```

I can store all the images in the database with no problem. The problem is when I want to show them in a **p:dataTable** like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTableLoadedPhotos"
                value="#{imageController.photographListUpdate}" var="image">
                <p:column headerText="Fotografías cargadas" width="110">
                    <o:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.getById(image.photographId)}"
                        alt="#{msgs['label.diagnostic.photograph.notFound']}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

I am using a **streamer** based on [The BalusC Code: ImageServlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html) and I tried to use [o:graphicImage](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) with no success, something is missing in mi code:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageStreamer {

@EJB
private PhotographService photographService;

public byte[] getById(Long id) {
    try {
        return photographService.getContent(id);
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        FacesMessage mensaje = new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Error al buscar la fotografía ", e.getMessage());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, mensaje);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I also have a managed bean with @RequestScoped:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ImageController {

@EJB
private PhotographService photographService;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{diagnosticDataManager}")
private DiagnosticDataManager diagnosticDataManager;

private List<Photograph> photographListUpdate = new ArrayList<Photograph>();
private Photograph selectedPhoto;

/**
 * 
 */
public ImageController() {
    diagnosticDataManager = new DiagnosticDataManager();
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (diagnosticDataManager.getDiagnostic().getDiagnosticId() != null)
        photographListUpdate = photographService
                .findPhotosByDiagnostic(diagnosticDataManager
                        .getDiagnostic());

    for (Photograph photograph : photographListUpdate) {
        byte[] imageContent = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
                .decodeBase64(photograph.getPhoto());
        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext();
        ec.getSessionMap()
                .put(photograph.getId().toString(),
                        imageContent);
    }
}
// Getters and setters....
}
```

I only see two rows in p:dataTable corresponding to the images preloaded with no image, just the message of "alt" attribute of the o:graphicImage is shown

Using firebug I only see this on each row:

```
<img alt="Imagen no encontrada" src="/patientdiagnostics/javax.faces.resource/ImageStreamer_getById.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.graphic&v=0&p=7">
```

I also tried something similar to [Display database blob images in <p:graphicImage> inside <ui:repeat>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073905/display-database-blob-images-in-pgraphicimage-inside-uirepeat?rq=1)

Comment: I use a p:fileUpload to save the image at DB, the init() method has `byte[] imageContent = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
                .decodeBase64(photograph.getPhoto());` because I saw in other questión, I am not sure if the images are stored as base64-encoded bytes, I just upload jpg image to the db, I thougth that I had to decode like that due to the image size, what could be the right way?

Comment: I removed all base64 stuff, I still see `<img alt="Imagen no encontrada" src="/patientdiagnostics/javax.faces.resource/ImageStreamer_getById.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.graphic&v=0&p=7">` and at browser's network I see `http://localhost:8080/patientdiagnostics/javax.faces.resource/ImageStreamer_getById.xhtml?ln=omnifaces.graphic&v=0&p=7`, it has a column wich says 200 OK (BFCache). If you need to see the method I use to save images to my db, please let me know

Comment: src="data:image;base64,"

Comment: I think I fix the method, now what I get is src="data:image;base64,AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA......AAAAAAA" but I can't see the image yet

Comment: Well, apparently it returned only zeroes.

Comment: Thank you BalusC you pointed me to the right direction, I was wrong saving my images into the db, now I can watch them through o:graphicImage and thanks to this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528671/primefaces-fileupload-to-byte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I can store all the images in the database with no problem.*

This was thus actually not true. Those images appear to be empty or filled with only zeroes.

How to grab the uploaded file content from a `<p:fileUpload>`, head to the following answers:

- [How to use PrimeFaces p:fileUpload? Listener method is never invoked or UploadedFile is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875818/how-to-use-primefaces-pfileupload-listener-method-is-never-invoked)
- [How to insert uploaded image from p:fileUpload as BLOB in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305633/how-to-insert-uploaded-image-from-pfileupload-as-blob-in-mysql/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that faces message which you're trying to add in the catch block of the streamer won't appear anywhere as the image request doesn't represent a JSF page. You'd better just log/mail it.